# Can Jedi get ill?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

Is there any canon or former canon evidence that Force-trained beings can protect themselves from viruses and the like? I know some Jedi can use the Force to heal injuries, and perhaps that Force-sensitives in general heal faster than others, but I couldn't find any references on that topic.

Comment: Well, Ahsoka almost dies of the blue shadow virus in The Clone Wars episode [Mystery of a Thousand Moons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_of_a_Thousand_Moons) and is only saved by an antidote, though I suppose this isn't definitive since she's still a Padawan.

Comment: Only if it's [time to get ill.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riEGPAFHE2M)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes...

There are various example of Force users contracting mundane diseases.

- Ahsoka Tano, Anakin's Padawan, contracted a virus in *The Clone Wars*: "Mystery of a Thousand Moons (1x18)"

  > PADME: ...can anyone hear—
  >
  > AHSOKA: Senator Amidala, we're trapped in the safe room at
  >   the end of Complex B.
  >
  > PADME: We'll be right there. Are you contaminated?
  >
  > AHSOKA: I'm afraid
  >   so.

  By the end of the episode, of course, Ahsoka is showing the effects of the virus quite clearly.

  Further, note:

  > VINDI: The virus is liberated. You are doomed, young Jedi, along with the rest of the planet.

  **This indicates that the scientist who made the virus, a presumed expert, believes that it can infect and kill Jedi.**
- Mara Jade, a Force user of some skill, was infected with coomb spores (a Yuuzhan Vong bioweapon), as were many others.

  > "You couldn't reach me before I threw this. It's full of coomb spores,
  >   Jade Skywalker. The spores I painted on a hundred abominable breath
  >   masks, before that outdoor ceremony." Mara's stomach lurched. "They
  >   didn't all sicken right away," she recalled. **She'd fallen ill two
  >   months later.**
  >
  > —*The New Jedi Order: Balance Point*

### ...but they can heal an illness or slow its course

- The Jedi Cilghal, perhaps the greatest healer the Jedi had,  was able to slow the course of Mara Jade's disease, although she was not truly cured until Vergere helped her. She also was able to save Mon Mothma from an infection of artificial nanodestroyers, a technique which probably would work on ordinary microorganisms.

  > Cilghal found other microscopic destroyers and nudged them, pushed
  >   them, herding the poison away from healthy cells, preventing further
  >   damage. The task was incomprehensibly large. The poison had spread and
  >   replicated, scattering itself through the billions and billions of
  >   cells in Mon Mothma's body. Cilghal would have to search and remove
  >   every one of them.
  >
  > —*Champions of the Force*
- It is suggested in the Star Wars RPG sourcebook *Power of the Jedi* that Jedi can use the Force to cure disease.

  [image]
- Vergere, a sometime Jedi Knight,  was able to use the *Art of the Small* to produce tears capable of healing many things, including the coomb spore that Mara Jade was infected with. Of course, this may have had something to do with her species, but the Force was definitely involved.

  > Liquid gems gathered at the corners of her eyes and rolled down her
  >   muzzle, gleaming in the misty green twilight. *Vergere's tears*...He
  >   remembered the little vial of tears, and Mara's sudden recovery from
  >   the coomb-spore infection that everyone had privately suspected would
  >   take her life.
  >
  > —*The New Jedi Order:Traitor*

**Therefore, Jedi (and other Force-users) are *not* immune to disease as a matter of course, but particularly strong individuals may be able to resist or cure illness.**

Comment: Mara Jade is definitely proof that even a well-trained Force user, as opposed to a Padawan like Ahsoka - can still be afflicted with biologically harmful ailments. Ultimately, I think it's all about one's mastery of the Force. Let's not forget that the restorative nature of the light side is why Jedi live healthier, less aged and longer lives than commoners of the same species, while the self-destructive nature of the dark side is the reason for the opposite, and why the Sith always seeks to lengthen their lives.

Comment: @thegreatjedi -  I'm glad you like it. Do you know which book Mara Jade contracts the coomb spores in?